# Insert repetitive values in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Does anybody now a easier way to insert values in a table when you have a lot of repetitive values.

I have 3 tables and for the sake of simplicity I made an zoo example out of it. One table list animals, one Zoos in USA and one which animals you can find in each zoo.

Table: Animals

```
   Id   Animal
   ---------------
   1.   Elephant
   2.   Lion
   3.   Tiger
   4.   Crocodile 
   5.   Bison
   .    .... 
   .    ....
```

Table: Zoos

```
   Id   Zoo
   ---------------
   1.   Alaska Zoo 
   2.   Little Rock Zoo
   3.   Big Bear Alpine Zoo 
   4.   Los Angeles Zoo
   5.   Oakland Zoo
   .    .... 
   .    ....
```

Table: AnimalInZoo

```
   Zooid    Animalid
   -------------------
   1          1
   1          2
   1          3
   1          4 
   1          5
   2          1
   2          2
   2          3
   2          4 
   2          5
```

To insert values into the AnimalinZoo table I now write:

```
INSERT INTO AnimalinZoo (zooid, animals)
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5);

INSERT INTO AnimalinZoo (zooid, animals)
VALUES (2, 1),  (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5);
```

Because I would like to insert this similar list of animal in a lot of zoo, is there a easier way to write this in sql so i don't have to repeat myself so much. Or can I insert value from the animal and zoo table directly into AnimalinZoo with SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a `cross join` if you want all animals in all zoos?

```
insert into animal_in_zoo (zooid, animalid)
    select z.id, a.id
    from zoos z cross join
         animals a;
```

Comment: Thx for your comment, but I don't want to join all animal and zoo. Can I use cross join and combine it with some where statement? Let say if I specificliy want to join zoo id 3,4,5 with animal id 1,4,6,8 (so that zooid 3,4,5 all have animaidl 1,4,6,8 in the  AnimalInZoo table.

Comment: Sure, simply add a`WHERE` clause after the `CROSS JOIN` that contains these two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a array for zoos and animals then unnest and cross join the results:

```
with animal_list as
     (select unnest(array[1,4,6,8]) animal)
   , zoo_list as 
     (select unnest(array[3,4,5]) zoo )
insert into animalInZoo (zoo_id, animal_id) 
       select zoo, animal
         from zoo_list cross join animal_list;
```

Or better (IMHO) encapsulate the process within a sql function taking the arrays as parameters.

```
create or replace function populate_zoo( zoos integer[], animals integer[] )
returns void 
language sql strict
as $$
    with animal_list as
         (select unnest(animals) animal)
       , zoo_list as 
         (select unnest(zoos) zoo )
    insert into animalInZoo (zoo_id, animal_id) 
        select zoo, animal
          from zoo_list cross join animal_list;
$$;

-- test 
do $$
begin
   perform populate_zoo(zoos    => '{3,4,5}'
                       ,animals => '{1,4,6,8}'
                       );
end; 
$$;
```

The above code set both produce the same result;